# App crashes on jellybean

Tags: java, api, crash

I am working on an application which working good at oreo to lollipop but at jellybean it crashes and I do not why?

My target sdk is 16

Mt min sdk is 15

And the log give me this:

> 08-26 10:00:24.098 87-393/? E/AudioFlinger: unkown mime type  08-26
>   10:00:25.278 11895-11895/com.example.abanoub.angelsbook
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abanoub.angelsbook/com.example.abanoub.angelsbook.DataActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at com.example.abanoub.angelsbook.DataActivity.onCreate(DataActivity.java:83)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
>           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  08-26 10:00:25.438 513-531/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k
>   -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error 08-26 10:00:32.018 782-782/? E/Launcher: Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found:
>   accessibility_enabled

and this is DataActivity

```
public class DataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   MyTextView Headlineview;

MyTextView Rightview;

MyTextView Leftview;

MyTextView Endview;

String DataToDisplay ;

  String Chosendate;
String you129 = "9/12";
String m29 = "9/2";




Typeface font;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("saved", SettingsActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fontsize = sp.getInt("size", -1);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int mnouth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle == null) {
        Chosendate = mnouth + 1 + "/" + day;
    } else {

        Chosendate = bundle.getString("chosen");
    }
    Headlineview = findViewById(R.id.headline);
    Rightview = findViewById(R.id.rightdataView);
    Leftview = findViewById(R.id.leftdataView);
    Endview = findViewById(R.id.enddataView);




    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    if (fontsize == -1 ) {


            Headlineview.setTextSize(17);
            Leftview.setTextSize(17);
            Rightview.setTextSize(17);
            Endview.setTextSize(17);

    }
    else {   Headlineview.setTextSize(fontsize);
        Leftview.setTextSize(fontsize);
        Rightview.setTextSize(fontsize);
        Endview.setTextSize(fontsize);}


       if (Chosendate.contentEquals(you129)) {
        Headlineview.setText(R.string.y129head);
        Leftview.setText(R.string.y129dataleft);
        Rightview.setText(R.string.y129dataright);
        Endview.setText(R.string.y129end);

    } else if (Chosendate.contentEquals(m29)) {
        Headlineview.setText(R.string.m29head);
        Leftview.setText(R.string.m29dataleft);
        Rightview.setText(R.string.m29dataright);
        Endview.setText(R.string.m29end);
        DataToDisplay= getText(R.string.m29share).toString();

    }



    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent shareintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                    DataToDisplay + " \n \n \n \n \n تطبيق تماجيد يوميه" +
                            "\n\n" +
                            " https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.abanoub.angelsbook" +
                            "\n\n");
            shareintent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(shareintent);

        }
    });
}}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}
```

}

and at mainActivity give that

```
**08-26 17:22:03.568 16368-16368/com.example.abanoub.angelsbook E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.abanoub.angelsbook.MainActivity.releaseInstance
    at com.example.abanoub.angelsbook.MainActivity.onStop(MainActivity.java:176)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1219)
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5326)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3039)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)**
```

Comment: Hello and welcme to Stackoverflow (often written SO). Please read [ask] to learn how to write a good question and [edit] your question. For instance you don't provide the relevant source code related to your problem, so how are we supposed to help you, thanks ?

Answer (score 0):

You've got NullPointerException at line 83 of class *DataActivity*, in the *onCreate()* Method.

See stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.abanoub.angelsbook.DataActivity.onCreate(DataActivity.java:83)
```

Can you please share the code of class DataActivity?